# Add notes on tikz-uml sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-uml

Is it possible to add some notes on tikz-uml diagram?
e.g. I wish to add "MSG_PERSIST_VOLUME" under handleMessage (below the arrow line).

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, positioning} 

\begin{document} 
\small\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{umlseqdiag} 
    \umlactor{user} 
    \umlobject{AudioService} 
    \umlobject[]{Settings} 
    \begin{umlcall}[op=handleMessage(),return=1]{user}{AudioService}
        \begin{umlcall}[op=persistVolume(),return=1]{AudioService}{AudioService}
             \begin{umlcall}[op=putIntForUser(),return=1]{AudioService}{Settings}
                \begin{umlcall}[op=putStringForUser(),return=1]{Settings}{Settings}
                \end{umlcall} 
             \end{umlcall} 
        \end{umlcall} 
    \end{umlcall}
  \end{umlseqdiag} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

 \end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to add only text? You can insert a text as node manually.

Comment: @ferahfeza Yes,but I wish to get some location info looks like " message1.south west", it's not good idea to use absolute coordinate since it maybe changed after insert more elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide the option `name=a` to the `umlcall` environment, the `op` node will be called `a-op` (and similarly, the `return` node is called `a-return`), so you can use that to position a node.

If you don't provide a `name`, those nodes are like `call-N-op`, where `N` is a counter for `umlcall`s starting at 1. In other words, if you leave out `name=a` in the code below, use `call-1-op.south` instead of `a.south`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 

\begin{document} 
\small\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{umlseqdiag} 
    \umlactor{user} 
    \umlobject{AudioService} 
    \umlobject[]{Settings} 
    \begin{umlcall}[op=handleMessage(),return=1,name=a]{user}{AudioService}
        \begin{umlcall}[op=persistVolume(),return=1]{AudioService}{AudioService}
             \begin{umlcall}[op=putIntForUser(),return=1]{AudioService}{Settings}
                \begin{umlcall}[op=putStringForUser(),return=1]{Settings}{Settings}
                \end{umlcall} 
             \end{umlcall} 
        \end{umlcall} 
    \end{umlcall}
  \end{umlseqdiag} 

\node [below,font=\scriptsize] at (a-op.south) {MSG\_PERSIST\_VOLUME};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```