# How to make a umlcall without a caller class in Tikz-uml sequence diagram?

Tags: tikz-uml

Can I make a call to a class without a caller class using `TikZ-uml` sequence diagrams? It would be just an arrow pointing at a timeline of a class beginning a new method as added in this picture created withe the code below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{umlseqdiag} 
\umlobject[class=A]{a} 
\umlobject[class=B]{b} 
\umlobject[class=C]{c} 
\begin{umlcall}{a}{b} 
\begin{umlcall}{b}{c} 
\end{umlcall} 
\end{umlcall} 
\end{umlseqdiag} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you add MWE and a picture?

Comment: Your code doesn't actually work properly, it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to [Add notes on tikz-uml sequence diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/add-notes-on-tikz-uml-sequence-diagram/389260#389260), the box at the start if the `umlcall` is a node named `st-call-N`, where `N` is the number of the `call` (counting from 1). So you can do for example

```
\draw [tikzuml synchron-msg style] ([xshift=-2cm]st-call-1.north west) node[left] {methodWithoutCaller()} -- (st-call-1.north west);
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{umlseqdiag} 
\umlobject[class=A]{a} 
\umlobject[class=B]{b} 
\umlobject[class=C]{c} 
\begin{umlcall}{a}{b} 
\end{umlcall} 
\begin{umlcall}{b}{c} 
\end{umlcall} 
\end{umlseqdiag} 
\draw [tikzuml synchron-msg style] ([xshift=-2cm]st-call-1.north west) node[left] {methodWithoutCaller()} -- (st-call-1.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```