# How to draw a gate with tikz-uml

Tags: tikz-uml

I would like to be able to draw a "gate" (described [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_sequencediagram.html)) on a sequence diagram, but I have not been able to figure out how to do that with tikz-uml. The closest I've been able to come is to use a \umlboundary, as shown in the code below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{umlseqdiag}
            \umlboundary[no ddots]{EXT}
            \umlobject[no ddots]{A}
            \umlobject[no ddots]{B}
            \umlobject[no ddots]{C}
            \begin{umlcall}[op=external]{EXT}{A}
            \end{umlcall}
            \begin{umlcall}[op=query, type=synchron, return=identify]
                {A}{B}
            \end{umlcall}
            \begin{umlcall}[op=hb, type=synchron, return=register]
                {B}{C}
            \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following diagram:
[image]

However, I don't want the circle, "EXT" label, lifeline, or rectangle associated with the umlboundary object, I want it to look something like this:
[image]

Is there some way to draw a gate with tikz-uml?

Comment: +1 (nice MWE) Maybe also show the desired output in the post (draw it by hand if necessary). A link can be broken in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added a diagram showing what I'm looking for.

Comment: If this is part of the UML spec, but not yet implemented in `tikz-uml`, I'd suggest contacting the maintainer (https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/) and making a feature request.

Comment: I went to this web site but I didn't see any way to request a new feature, or even a forum. Do you know how I would go about making a feature request?

Comment: Email link can be found at https://uma.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi.  (Didn't see your comment until now. If you want a user to be notified of a comment, write a `@` immediately followed by the username, e.g. @Gary. Tab-completion is available. Only other commenters and editors, and only one user per comment, can be notified. Because you wrote the post the comments belong to, you're always notified.)

Comment: That said: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347900/how-to-make-a-umlcall-without-a-caller-class-in-tikz-uml-sequence-diagram/389273#389273, but try something like `\draw [tikzuml synchron-msg style] ([xshift=-2cm]st-call-1.north west) node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] {} -- (st-call-1.north west);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a umlcall without a caller class in Tikz-uml sequence diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347900/how-to-make-a-umlcall-without-a-caller-class-in-tikz-uml-sequence-diagram)